# Call object function in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I use RequireJS to load some scripts.

Now I would like to create some own methods which also needs the loaded script. I've tried a lot but I always get `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: hd is not defined`. Both scripts are loaded in my index.html.

**Calling the method 'connect' from main.js**

```
hd.connect.call(token);
```

**socket-workers.js**

```
...
require.config({

shim: {
    'socket.io': {
      exports: 'io'
    },
    'socket.io-stream': {
      exports: 'ss'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'socket.io': WEBSOCKET_PROXY_HOST + '/socket.io/socket.io',
    'socket.io-stream': WEBSOCKET_PROXY_HOST + '/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream'
  },
  waitSeconds: 1

});

requirejs([
  'socket.io', 'socket.io-stream'
], function(io, ss) {

  // Setup Methods & Events

  const hd = {

    connect : function(token) {
      // Connect to Socket, Proxy Server & authenticate
      socket = io(WEBSOCKET_PROXY_HOST, {
        auth: {
          token: token
        }
      }).on('connect', function(data) {
        socketConnected = true;
        isStreaming = false;
        console.log('connected to socket');
        if (activeRecording) {
          //#startRecording();
        }
      });
...
```

Comment: Don't think theres enough info here. Where are you calling hd.connect.call(token)?

Comment: oh sorry, I have two scripts main.js and socket-workers.js and I want to create a kind of SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS can be used this way, but there is a more proper way - define a module and then require it while defining another module:

socket-workers.js:

```js
require.config({

shim: {
    'socket.io': {
      exports: 'io'
    },
    'socket.io-stream': {
      exports: 'ss'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    'socket.io': WEBSOCKET_PROXY_HOST + '/socket.io/socket.io',
    'socket.io-stream': WEBSOCKET_PROXY_HOST + '/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream'
  },
  waitSeconds: 1

});

define('hd', [
  'socket.io', 'socket.io-stream'
], function(io, ss) {

  // Setup Methods & Events

  const hd = {

    connect : function(token) {
      // Connect to Socket, Proxy Server & authenticate
      socket = io(WEBSOCKET_PROXY_HOST, {
        auth: {
          token: token
        }
      }).on('connect', function(data) {
        socketConnected = true;
        isStreaming = false;
        console.log('connected to socket');
        if (activeRecording) {
          //#startRecording();
        }
      });
    );



    return hd;
```

main.js:

```js
define(['hd'], function (hd) {
  hd.connect.call(token);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a solution to solve this issue. I've added

```
window.hd = hd;
```

within the function to make the methods available.

Now I can call every method with for e.g. `hd.connect(), hd.disconnect()`

Comment: Without seeing the code in `main.js` from which the function is called its not clear whether this work around is necessary if the answer itself is kind of meaningless. Intuitively, I would think that `hd` should be exported from a third module via `define` as in `// hd.js define(['socket.io', 'socket.io-stream'], function (io, ss) { var hd = {...}; return hd; });` and then in main `// main.js requirejs(['./hd.js'], function (hd) { hd.connect(token); });`